# Oracle hangs while updating table

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am updating a table with statement

```
update asdf123 
   set state='Rlzd' 
 where documentname = '11212121212' 
   and superseded = '-';
```

But it hangs indefinitely.

I checked the session, got a hanged session, then killed it and the above session was killed. Again same situation happens.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Some other session is blocking the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you killed the blocked session(your session)
Use something like this to find blocking session:

```
SELECT
   s.blocking_session, 
   s.sid, 
   s.serial#, 
   s.seconds_in_wait
FROM
   v$session s
WHERE
   blocking_session IS NOT NULL
```

See another ways to find them: http://www.oraclerecipes.com/monitoring/find-blocking-sessions/

Comment: In the bloking session I found only single sid which , I was killing and my session was also killed.